# Java TreeSet<Long []> comparable based on array's first element

Tags: java, treeset

For the following codes:

```
    TreeSet<Long[]> ts = new TreeSet<Long[]>();
    ts.add(new Long[] {22L,22L});
    ts.add(new Long[] {2L,22L});
    ts.add(new Long[] {24L,22L});
    ts.add(new Long[] {11L,22L});
    ts.add(new Long[] {7L,22L});
```

It throws:

```
Ljava.lang.Long; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

Because the `Long []` doesn't realize `comparable`

Is there a neat way to let the `Long []` added into the `TreeSet` sorted based on `Long []`'s first element?

Comment: You can provide a custom comparator to the constructor when you compare the first values of the arrays.

Comment: I would create a `Pair` or `Coord` class that stores the two `Long` values and implement a proper `Comparator` rather than using this approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't passed a `Comparator` to the `TreeSet` constructor, so the `TreeSet` will rely on its items being `Comparable`.  But they aren't `Comparable`, hence the exception.

Pass a `Comparator<Long[]>` to [the constructor that takes one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-), so the `TreeSet` knows how you want the `Long[]`s compared.

```
TreeSet<Long[]> ts = new TreeSet<Long[]>(
   new Comparator<Long[]>() {
      public int compare(Long[] a, Long[] b)
      {
         return Long.compare(a[0], b[0]);
      }
   }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can initialize a TreeSet with a Comparator:

```
TreeSet<Long[]> ts = new TreeSet<Long[]>( new Comparator<Long[]>() { ... });
```

This allows you to compare the Long-array by the first element. Alternatively you could create a Wrapper class that implements Comparable and that holds the array.